# nodejs cannot read javasscript file in html

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

Node js keep giving me file not found error ..

my directory structure :

```
app
   --main
   --app.js
   --bootstrap.js
   --route.js
 bower_components
   --requirejs
      --require.js     
 app.js
 index.html
```

I believe this code should put all the static files in directory to middleware stacks.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/app')))
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/bower_components')))

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});
```

This is my html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
   <div style="color:red"> hello I am in index11</div>

    <div ng-view></div>
   <script type="text/javascript"  src="app/test.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  data-main="app/app.js" src="bower_components/requirejs/require.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting string in html. However, I see this error from 
chrome developer tool

Remote Address:[::1]:3000
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/bower_components/requirejs/require.js
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found

Answer (score 0):

Why not let `express` [build](http://expressjs.com/starter/generator.html) your site and modify it from there?

```
%> npm install -g express-generator
%> express my-app-name
```

Comment: Yes, I did and I deleted public and view directory to use angular route

Comment: Then how is express supposed to serve up the content? Your route isn't public.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove **bower_components** or  **app** from the paths in index.html 
It will start working. As you have **bower_components** or  **app** in 
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '****')))

Comment: I should be able to read it in order to use requirejs and other css such as bootstrap.